# xpages open same database over iframes

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs

I have an php application which integrate over widgets/iframes 4 xpages-apps. 
every single app work alone perfect, but when I integrate them on the widget dashboard, often one or two apps getting an Error by opening a database.

```
Caused by: com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script-Interpreterfehler, Zeile=3, Spalte=32:  [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesSession.getDatabase(string, string) null
```

and

```
Caused by: NotesException: User XXX cannot open database Server!!path\name.nsf
```

The User has access to the database.
If I refresh the iframe/widget it works fine.
It looks like that the system crashs, when a user like to access the same database 2 times.

anybody out there to solve my problem.

Comment: When you say "access the same database 2 times", do you mean open it in two iframes at the same time?

Comment: Double check the path - backslash needs to be escaped, or use slash.

Comment: Yes @DavidNavarre the 2 xpages are in one database.
But the database that I can't access is a second, which I connect over ssjs NotesSession.getdatabase(...) in each iframe.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth the path is 'path\\database.nsf'

Comment: Can you provide the code, rather than trying to explain.